# java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL:

Tags: java, rest, https, etl, informatica-powercenter

I am trying to call REST API from Informatica Java transformation and the java code is as below, the Id and Email are two fields I am getting from previous transformation (source file). When I test with actual values of access token, Id and Email , the request works but when i give  the field names I get 500 error.

```java
try {
    URL url = new URL("https://ditabc.com");
    HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", access_token);
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
    String requestBody = "[{\"Id\":\"Id\", \"EmailId\":\"EmailId\"}]";
    try (OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream()) {
        byte[] input = requestBody.getBytes("utf-8");
        os.write(input, 0, input.length);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

    //    String line;

    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

    if (conn.getResponseCode() == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(line);
        }
        final_response = response.toString();
    }
    reader.close();
    conn.disconnect();
} catch (Exception e) {
    logInfo("Error");
    final_response = e.toString();
}
```

I am trying to call the end point URL here. Can you help if the error response is due to the server not reachable or any issue in the code?

Comment: 500 means "Internal Server Error", meaning that the server received your request, but wasn't able to handle it for some reason. The "some reason" should be in the response that you received if the server is properly coded. If you have this reason, please share it. If you only receive 500 Internal Server Error without any further explanation, is hard to say anything.

Comment: now i am able to post the data, but the 200 code is only showing in logs , there is null in the final_response . the http response code is not captured .